# Best way to archive or backup node_modules folder in Node.js/NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm in need to archive all the dependencies of a NodeJS project that uses NPM. My need is quite peculiar, as we should be able to return to a know state if necessary, not depending at all to internet repositories (offline). We tried to set up a private registry, but some finalizer scripts still needs connection to GitHub and similia to download files. At now we archive the"Node_Modules" folder, is it correct or it may create some troubles with other PCs or configurations?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I come up with a solution. Because this is an industrial grade application, I simply compressed and backuped the node_modules. I tried in a fresh VM without any network connection with new installation of Windows 10 and development tools (all offline packages). My two cents are: if you need to backup node_modules for developing support in some years, backup OS and Tools offline installers and zipped node_modules should do. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: it would be nice if you post some code, which illustrate your answer.

Comment: I didn't made any particular code. When we need to preserve the repository for the code, we compress the folder node_modules and give the same hash of the Master release commit. If in the future (like, in 8 or 9 years) we need to service a particular release, we will install from our archives the right Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 from an offline repository, NPM and Node.js from an offline executable, expand node_modules, checkout the Master code and start fixing them. Easy and working. Hope this helps :)